# How can I write files in Deno?

Tags: javascript, deno

I was trying to write to a file using `Deno.writeFile`

```
await Deno.writeFile('./file.txt', 'some content')
```

But got the following cryptic error:

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: arr.subarray is not a function
    at Object.writeAll ($deno$/buffer.ts:212:35)
    at Object.writeFile ($deno$/write_file.ts:70:9)
```

What's the right way to write files in Deno?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are multiple ways to write a file in Deno, all of them require `--allow-write` flag and will `throw` if an error occurred, so you should handle errors correctly.

### Using [`Deno.writeFile`](https://deno.land/api@v1.25.3?s=Deno.writeFile)

This API takes a `Uint8Array`, not a **string**, the reason why you get that error. It also takes an optional [`WriteFileOptions`](https://deno.land/api@v1.25.3?s=Deno.WriteFileOptions) object

```js
const res = await fetch('http://example.com/image.png');
const imageBytes = new Uint8Array(await res.arrayBuffer());
await Deno.writeFile('./image.png', imageBytes);
```

There's also the synchronous API (it blocks the event loop as it does in Node.js).

```js
Deno.writeFileSync('./image.png', imageBytes);
```

### Writing strings

---

The easiest way is to use [`Deno.writeTextFile`](https://deno.land/api@v1.25.3?s=Deno.writeTextFile)

```js
await Deno.writeTextFile('./file.txt', 'some content');
```

You can also use `Deno.writeFile` with `TextEncoder`.

```
const encoder = new TextEncoder(); // to convert a string to Uint8Array
await Deno.writeFile('./file.txt', encoder.encode('some content'));
```

### Streaming

[`Deno.open`](https://deno.land/api@v1.25.3?s=Deno.open) returns a [FsFile](https://deno.land/api@v1.25.3?s=Deno.FsFile) which contains a `WritableStream` in `.writable` property, so you can just pipe a stream directly to it.

```
const res = await fetch('https://example.com/csv');
const file = await Deno.open('./some.csv', { create: true, write: true })

await res.body.pipeTo(file.writable);
file.close();
```

If you have a `Reader` instead of a `ReadableStream` you can convert it to a `ReadableStream` using `readableStreamFromReader` from `std/streams`:

```
import { readableStreamFromReader } from "https://deno.land/std@0.156.0/streams/mod.ts?s=readableStreamFromReader";

// ...

const readable = readableStreamFromReader(someReader);
await readable.pipeTo(file.writeable)
```

### Low-level APIs

Using `Deno.open` and `Deno.writeAll` (or `Deno.writeAllSync`)

```
const file = await Deno.open('./image.png', { write: true, create: true });
/* ... */
await Deno.writeAll(file, imageBytes);
file.close(); // You need to close it!
```

See `OpenOptions` [here](https://deno.land/api@v1.25.3?s=Deno.OpenOptions). If you want to append you would do:

```
{ append: true }
```

And you can also use even lower-level APIs such as [`Deno.write`](https://deno.land/api@v1.25.3?s=Deno.write) or [`Writer.write`](https://deno.land/api@v1.25.3?s=Deno.Writer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ensureDir`](https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/fs/ensure_dir.ts#L10) to safely [write files](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.writeTextFile) to possibly non-existent directories:

```
import { ensureDir } from "https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/fs/ensure_dir.ts";

ensureDir("./my/dir")
  .then(() => Deno.writeTextFile("./my/dir/file.txt", "some content"));
```

The containing file directory can be derived via [`dirname`](https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/path/posix.ts#L184):

```
import { dirname } from "https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/path/mod.ts";

const file = "./my/dir/file.txt";
ensureDir(dirname(file)).then(() => Deno.writeTextFile(file, "some content"));
```

An alternative is [`ensureFile`](https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/fs/ensure_file.ts#L15) to assert file existence:

```
import { ensureFile } from "https:deno.land/std/fs/ensure_file.ts";

ensureFile(file).then(/* your file write method */)
```

This variant is slightly less verbose, with the cost of one additional write operation (file creation, if not exists).