# convert base64 qrcode to jpg or png in deno

Tags: typescript, deno

I wrote this code in `app.ts` file:

```
const image = await qrcode(text);
const imgTag = `<img src="${image}" alt="qrcode" />`;
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
await Deno.writeFile("./qr.html", encoder.encode(imgTag));
```

the problem its to output it's in an HTML file but I want to convert base 64 images to jpg or png. How to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I write files in Deno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019830/how-can-i-write-files-in-deno)

Answer (score 0):

To encode a `Uint8Array` (which I assume is what `qrcode` returns) into `base64`, you can use `std/encoding`.

```js
import { encode } from 'https://deno.land/std/encoding/base64.ts'

const image = await qrcode(text);
// use correct mime: png or jpeg
const imgTag = `<img src="data:image/png;base64,${encode(image.buffer)}" alt="qrcode" />`;
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
await Deno.writeFile("./qr.html", encoder.encode(imgTag))
```